# If a property receives a value from an internal stylesheet & inline styling, was that value received a 'specified value'?

Tags: html, css

This [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/specified_value) states:

> The specified value of a CSS property is the value it receives from the document's style sheet.

What counts as a document's style-sheet?

My intuition says:

External stylesheet (from user, author & user-agent) counts.

I'm not sure if internal stylesheet (`style` tag) & internal styling (`style` property) count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To better understand refer to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#specified-value) where you can read:

> 1. If the cascade results in a value, use it. Except that, if the value is 'inherit', the specified value is defined in “The 'inherit' value” below.

*The cascade* is more explicit than *the document's style sheet*.

If you continue in the specification you will find:

> **Author**. The author specifies style sheets for a source document according to the conventions of the document language. For instance, in HTML, **style sheets may be included in the document or linked externally**.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#cascade)</sup>

So it's clear that all the CSS is considered even the internal styling and the inline one which is logical.

You can see the rules as follow:

1. If a CSS is applied to the element we use it
2. If nothing is applied we see if the property is inherited. If yes we use the value from the parent. If no we use the initial value.